# Exclamation mark prefix on variables during if statements and other as well?

Tags: swift, if-statement, syntax, logic

I'm very confused even after looking through similar questions of what the(!) operator does when it is prefixed on a variable or other object in if statements, functions, etc?

```
Example:  

mutating func add(value: T) 
   {  
        if !contains(items, value)
          {
          items.append(value)  
          }
   }
```

Comment: `!` is the "logical NOT" operator in Swift (and some other languages). All Swift operators are documented in the Swift book.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the exclamation mark `!` is used for two purposes. When you see it appear at the beginning of an object, such as in `!contains(items, values)`, it means "NOT". For example...

```
let x = 10
let y = 5

if x == y {
print("x is equal to y")
} else if x != y {
print("x is NOT equal to y")
}
```

The above code will print => "`x is NOT equal to y`" .

The logical NOT (`!`) operator can be used to reverse boolean values. For example...

```
    var falseBoolValue = false

    falseBoolValue = !falseBoolValue
    print(falseBoolValue)
```

The above code will print => "`true`"

In addition to the usage as the logical NOT operator, the exclamation mark is also used to implicitly unwrap optional values. Whenever you see the exclamation mark appear at the end of an object name, such as in `someVariable!`, it is being used to implicitly unwrap an optional value. Read about optionals to gain a better understanding of how `!` is used with optional values.

Comment: I've studied swift for over 4 months now and I know so much about it but the sad thing is that I'm having a hard time with the ! operator only when it is prefixed on a variable in a conditional statement. Optionals and the rest are all easy. I'm still confused on our example of the not operator.....Why does the above example that you gave ,return a true? Shouldn't it return false because false = !false is ultimately false because the !false gets changed into a true?

Comment: You are mis-reading `=` as `==`. In the above example, we first initialize `falseBoolValue` and give it a value of `false`. Then we change its value, to the opposite of itself by doing `falseBoolValue = !falseBoolValue`. And the opposite of `false` is `true`, therefore it prints true. If, however, we wrote `print(falseBoolValue == !falseBoolValue)`, then it would print `false` since we are evaluating the statement. This really comes down to the fact that `=` is used to set a new value to a property, where as `==` is used to compare multiple values.

Comment: let me know if you would like more clarification

Comment: ohhh i see, well that clears up a whole lot, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

it is NOT prefix there. Meaning your if looks for "items NOT containing value".